# Having an issue Deploying to Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, npm-install

I keep getting the below error while trying to deploy my application:

```
INFO [ccdd6005] Running cd /home/deployer/mcg/current/react-client && npm install as deployer@xx.xx.xx.xx
DEBUG [ccdd6005] Command: cd /home/deployer/mcg/current/react-client && npm install
DEBUG [ccdd6005]    bash: npm: command not found
```

Does anyone have any idea why npm would fail even though I SSH into the machine and run `npm install` successfully?

Comment: A few questions for you: Where are you deploying? Are you deploying to your own server with capistrano? When you SSH into the machine, do you login as the same user as your capistrano script?

Comment: I am deploying to a remote server that my company owns in a public cloud. I do login as the deployer user. Also, I do have an account with the same username on the server as the local machine I am running the Capistrano script from. Could this be it?

Comment: Hmm.. and capistrano is deploying as the deployer user as well? In your deploy.rb file, do you have a line for `set :user, "deployer"`? Sorry if this sounds like obvious stuff, I'm just trying to understand your setup so far.

Comment: Ya, the Capistrano script execute as deployer and has that same line in the script. I am new to cap and ruby and ror and everything I have looked at seems to be in order.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because nvm doesn't install node in the usual place `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm` and once I installed node without nvm it worked.